# NiFi decimal number format

Tags: apache-nifi

Given the CSV input file below:

```
name,amount
Abc,"1,234.56"
Def,"2,222,222.222222"
```

The amount field contains decimal number with comma. How to parse it into a number in NiFi? I don't want to parse it into a string.

I thought of using the UpdateRecord processor, Expression Language, and Java's NumberFormat to parse it, but it seems that NumberFormat is inaccessible from Expression Language. Alternatively, I want to use ScriptedRecordSetWriter to parse, but couldn't find any working example out there.

Appreciate any help especially with a working example.

Comment: Did you try the to have the number as number (without quotes) maybe this way NiFi can manage it properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When we are **reading** the incoming data we still needs to use `String type(as the data is enclosed in ")` while writing out the data from UpdateRecord processor we can use `int/decimal` types to write the output flowfile records.

***1. Using Record Path Value:***

You can read the incoming data as **String** datatype, Output flowfile will have integer type defined() and using UpdateRecord processor [replace](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html#substringbefore) the **','** with **''**

Add new property in UpdateRecord processor as

**/amount**

```
substringBefore(replace(/amount,',',''),'.')
```

[image]

Now the output flowfile will have integer datatype for the amount field.

***2. Using Literal Value:***

If we are using literal value we can use [NiFi expression language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#replace) functions on **field.value** by using `replace` and `toNumber` functions we are able to get int value for amount field.
[image]

Both ways we are going to get output flowfile in json format as

```
[{"name":"Abc","amount":1234},{"name":"Def","amount":2222222}]
```

In the same way if you want to have decimal as output flowfile type define **avro schema with decimal type** and don't use **substringBefore** and **toNumber** functions.